# Automation error when creating scatter plot

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a scatter plot using VBA. The data source should be two disjoint columns. It even worked once. However after I filled one column of table using another VBA code it crashed. Tried to google it but to no avail. Hope someone could help!!

```
Sub XY_Chart()

    Dim r1, r2, rngDataSource As Range
    Dim iDataRowsCt As Long
    Dim iDataColsCt As Integer
    Dim iSrsIx As Integer
    Dim chtChart As Chart
    Dim srsNew As Series

    Set r1 = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C88111")
    Set r2 = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E88111")
    Set rngDataSource = Application.Union(r1, r2)
        With rngDataSource
            iDataRowsCt = .Rows.Count
            iDataColsCt = .Columns.Count
        End With
        '' Create the chart
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
            Left:=ActiveSheet.Columns(ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn).Left + _
                ActiveWindow.Width / 4, _
            Width:=ActiveWindow.Width / 2, _
            Top:=ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveWindow.ScrollRow).Top + _
                ActiveWindow.Height / 4, _
            Height:=ActiveWindow.Height / 2).Chart

        With chtChart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterline

            '' Remove any series created with the chart
            Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
                .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
            Loop

            For iSrsIx = 1 To iDataColsCt - 1 Step 2
                '' Add each series
                Set srsNew = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                With srsNew
                    .Name = rngDataSource.Cells(1, iSrsIx + 1)
                    .Values = rngDataSource.Cells(2, iSrsIx + 1) _
                        .Resize(iDataRowsCt - 1, 1)
                    .XValues = rngDataSource.Cells(2, iSrsIx) _
                        .Resize(iDataRowsCt - 1, 1)
                End With
            Next
        End With
End Sub
```

And I have another piece of code that should do the same.
It gives mistake on

.Chart.PlotBy = xlRows

The mistake is Run-time error '-2147221504' (80040000)
Automation error
Invalid OLEVERB structure

```
Sub GRPH()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim average, std As Double
    Dim cht  As Object
    Dim r1, r2, r3 As Range


    'Find the last Row with data in a Column
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

        Set r1 = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C88111")
        Set r2 = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E88111")
        Set r3 = Application.Union(r1, r2)
        Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=300, Top:=10, Height:=300)

    With cht
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=r3
        .Chart.PlotBy = xlRows
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. Can you give us the line where it throws an error?

Comment: this line
.ChartType = xlXYScatterline

Comment: Change it to `.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines`.

Comment: Moved my comment to answers section. If you found this helpful, kindly accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: could you please look at the extension of my question, there's another small piece of code that should do the same and returns error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `.ChartType` to `xlXYScatterlines`. It'd be best during times like this to record a macro and get the proper chart type from there, especially when it's throwing an error on the chart type line. ;)